# Get-ADGroupMember can't find group that absolutely exists

Tags: active-directory, powershell

When I try to pull members of a group, I get an error that nothing with that name exists. I tried both the name and SID. However, if I just try to ID the group (Get-ADGroup) it finds it just fine.

What gives? It's a universal security group.

```perl
PS U:\> Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Enterprise Admins" -Recursive
```

```
Get-ADGroupMember : There is no such object on the server
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Enterprise Admins" -Recursive
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enterprise Admins:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory 
   .Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

```perl
PS U:\> Get-ADGroupMember -Identity S-1-5-21-27620331-1835664617-1757479407-519 -Recursive
```

```
Get-ADGroupMember : There is no such object on the server
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity S-1-5-21-27620331-1835664617-1757479407-5 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (S-1-5-21-276203...-1757479407-519:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory 
   .Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

```perl
PS U:\> Get-ADGroup -Identity 'S-1-5-21-27620331-1835664617-1757479407-519'
```

```
DistinguishedName : CN=Enterprise Admins,OU=xxxxxxx,DC=xxxxxxxxx,DC=xxxxx
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Universal
Name              : Enterprise Admins
ObjectClass       : group
ObjectGUID        : 53fde7bf-a276-4a74-8442-b47c7b0aa3d8
SamAccountName    : Enterprise Admins
SID               : S-1-5-21-27620331-1835664617-1757479407-519
```

### EDIT

I switched my drive letter to C just to be sure. No change.

```perl
PS C:\> Get-ADGroupmember -Identity 'S-1-5-21-27620331-1835664617-1757479407-519'
```

```
Get-ADGroupmember : There is no such object on the server
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupmember -Identity 'S-1-5-21-27620331-1835664617-1757479407- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (S-1-5-21-276203...-1757479407-519:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory 
   .Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Comment: Have you tried silly things like making sure PowerShell is running as admin? When you check the group members from the GUI, are there any that show up as SIDs indicating they don't exist anymore? The error being thrown might not indicate the group wasn't found but one of the members wasn't.

Comment: @RyanBolger (1) I'm running as admin (2) There's definitely active members in there. My own account as well as some new hires are in there, and you can see "Enterprise Admins" in the "member of" section of their own object in AD. Thanks for the response!

Comment: What happens when you pipe the Get-ADGroup to Get-ADGroupMember?

Comment: @Semicolon, I'm really sorry, but I'm a beginner with powershell. I know that piping sort of strings the results into the next but I'm not quite sure how to format it with my current situation.

Comment: Get-AdGroup 'Enterprise Admins' | Get-AdGroupMember

Comment: Also - you're running this is the forest root domain, right?  Not a child domain?  I would test it for you, but my test environment is down at the moment and my "Enterprise Admins" group is explicitly empty (as it should almost always be).

Comment: @semicolon, No dice. "There is no such object on the server".

I've ran it in the forest root (which consists of 3 domains) and on a child domain.

Comment: Just to check, you might want to make sure no one else on your team is changing names between the time you start your script and the time it checks that name. I encountered the same thing; my issue was that I collected all AD groups with `Get-ADGroup -Properties *` and stored them in a CSV file. Then I import that file and for each `$Group` run `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.DistinguishedName`. Someone had changed one of the OUs (which is part of the DistinguishedName) for some of the groups to something else *after* I started the script, but before it got to those groups for step 2.